# Is there a way to use the Universal Tracker SDK from a controller rendering?

Tags: tracking, universal-tracker

It seems that SitecoreUTSessionBuilder make async calls, and controller rendering can't have async calls in them.  Am I misunderstanding something?  Is there a way to use the SDK from Sitecore?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to use UT in sitecore? Could you provide more details? You can use XConnectClient directly to trigger events or what do you need. Anyway, if you really need it in controller rendering you can use it like  "var eventResponse = session.TrackEventAsync(eventRequest).Result; " or use ConfigureAwait method.